# Percentage Arithmatic

Tags: arithmetic

> To pass an examination, 40% marks are essential. A obtain 10% marks
>   less than the pass marks and B obtains 11.11% marks less than A. What
>   percent less than the sum of a's and b's marks should c obtain to pass
>   the exam?
>   (a)40% (b)41(3/17)% (c)28% (d)Any of these

Let total marks be =100

A's marks=36

B's marks=24

A+B=60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total $=100$
$A=(100*40\%)*90\%=36$
$B=36*(100-11.11)\%=36*8/9=32$
$A+B=68$

AtMost 28 marks can be lost

$\frac{28}{68}*100\%=\frac{700}{17}\%=41\frac3{17}\%$

Comment: Answer is given "Any of these" :(

Comment: And that is correct since 41 is the upper limit. Even if they obtain say 40% less or 15% less they'd still pass